what is this toilet tank part called?
I believe there is a leak coming from the toilet tank and it is because of this part. I don't know what is it called. Can you please help me out?
Inside view of the part in the tank:

Outside view of the part underneath the tank:


It should be one of the two tank hold down bolts.  If hand tightening the wing nut does not help, then you will need new washers/seals.  Most stores with a plumbing section should carry them.

so its called tank to bowl kit?

That is a tank to bowl bolt.  It anchors the tank with the fill valve, flush valve and workings of the toilet and of course the water, to the bowl.
They can be purchased separately if needed and usually have some type of sealing washer. ( There are a few different types.)
If your goal is to replace them, Remove a bolt and take it to your hardware store to be matched up.  When installing the new bolts it is very important to not overtighten.  Usually it's best to tighten until the tank is mounted just firm. Then turn the water on and check for leaks.

Correct answer.  But I have never in my life had one of these fail.  @Asdfg you should try to determine why it failed before you replace it.  If the toilet is so old that the rubber has degraded, you may be better off replacing the toilet than making a repair like this.  If the bolt and washers used were the wrong ones, you should not buy the same ones.  Etc.   This is not a "maintenance" part, so should not be mindlessly replaced without thought to why.

I respectfully disagree.   I have had quite a few instances where the rubber washers degraded and the bolts were quite degraded too, causing a seeping of water.  Replacement cured the problem.  It does vary with the condition of the community water and if the homeowner uses any bowl cleaner additives in the tank.

Useful, @RMDman.   I OTOH have had toilets over 60 years old with various fatal failures  but with intact original tank bolts. Good info.

Thank you. Went to hardware store and bought the 2 in kit that had everything I needed. I guess I could have just changed the gasket/sealer on one of the bolts but the whole thing was $8 so just replaced it. No more water drips.

Some of the cleaners that people put in the tanks will degrade the rubber seals.

@jay613 they sometimes fail because the rubber washer deteriorates, just like the rubber in the flapper, or the tank-to-bowl drain seal.
